# Calling server-side C# function from either javascript or codebehind c# function ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, web

I want to call a function in an API that lives in a foreign server and get the result of this function. I want to do all this through a button click on an ASP.NET page on the client side. For simplicity, let's say this function takes in some parameter, appends a string to it and returns it. I want to render this returned string on the webpage. Lets say this is the server-side function:

```
public string Appender(string x)
{
     return x + "1";
}
```

Now, lets say I have a button on my asp.net webpage:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Search" />
```

And a label:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

My question is, what would go inside the Button1_Click function to call Appender (which is on the server-side)?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
 //TODO, call Appender, get result, set Label1's text to the returned string.
}
```

Or, should I be using javascript within the asp.net page to do this? I haven't messed around with javascript/ajax much so if that's the way to go, some guidance in that would be helpful also. Thanks.

Comment: What type is Appender a method of? Doesn't happen to be an ApiController does it?

Comment: So the "Appender" method is on a server you don't conrol and are accessing via an API? Is there any API documentation? What does it recomemnt?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I was confused. I guess the URL of the webpage would connect you to the server, so the webpage/API would basically be on the same server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what would go inside the Button1_Click function to call Appender

Call to the appender method will go here. Say the name of class that has this method is ClassA. The you will create an instance of ClassA and call the method. Like

```
ClassA obj = new ClassA();
obj.Appender("yourstring");
```

Comment: but ClassA is not local. It is on the server-side.

Comment: your click event is also on server side. So, both of them reside at the same place.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I represented it wrong. Basically the client goes to a webpage, clicks a button which calls the function on a server and gets the result.

Comment: Maybe, you don't understand how webpages work. Button click is a server side function and call is sent back to server to execute the code.

Comment: What if someone wants to call functions from the API through something like powershell?

Comment: sorry, didn't get your question. What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: I think I see what you're saying.. What is the point of using javascript to call server-side functions then? Sorry if that's a stupid question..

Comment: Google "uses of Ajax". You will get a detailed answer for that.

Comment: I see, so mainly preventing page reloads..?

Comment: Yes. You can say that broadly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if the function was on a separate server, what would be the way to call it?

Comment: Expose it through API/Webservice and call it.

Comment: I mean if I want to call it from that same button1_click function on this server.

Comment: If that method is on some other server. Then you will have to first make some webservie/api to expose that method. Then on the click event you can call that method through that webservice.